# ionic - Install upgrade 1.2.1 "amsterdam"

Tags: android, scroll, ionic-framework, upgrade

I have got big issue to make my app working smoothly on android compare to iOS (samsung GNII 4.4.2 and S3 4.3). it seems I am not the only one to point it out. **Main issue is the laggy scroll by default on android.**

So I decided to upgrade to ionic 1.2.1 "amsterdam" to try resolving scroll issues and avoid to whrite down overflow-scroll="true" into each

To upgrade to ionic 1.2.1 "amsterdam" I merely copied/pasted the content of the [zip file](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/releases/tag/v1.2.1) provided on ionic blog onto my project files. But I noticed that does not work : I do not have the native scroll by default on apk even if many files have been updated (I check [these lines](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/11946ef) for example and it s OK).

**So, where is my mistake please ?** I would like to test the last upgrades to check if ionic is able to make my app working well on android.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

For Android v4.4 and below, you need Crosswalk.

```
$ ionic browser add crosswalk
```

for your reference: http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/browsers.html

Also, it is good to install the latest Crosswalk version. You find it here: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html

Comment: I heard a bit about Crosswalk, I need to explore this feature. But that does not explain why my update and the process I uses (copy/paste) doesn t work ?